# CSS - Remove Start Animation

Tags: html, css

Let me get this off before I ask the question. I do not want to use jQuery.

I want this menu to grow and shrink on `hover` like so:

```
@keyframes menugrow {
  0% {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
  }
  25% {
    width:20%;
    height:25px;
  }
  100% {
    height:100vh;
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

and to shrink I do like so:

```
@keyframes menushrink {
  0% {
    width:20%;
    height:100vh;
  }
  75% {
    width:20%;
    height:25px;
  }
  100% {
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
  }
}
```

And here's what I have to activate these two:

```
.menu {
  background:#1a1a1a;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  animation: menushrink 0.3s linear;

}
.menu:hover {
  animation: menugrow 0.3s linear;
  height:100vh;
  width:20%;
}
```

All I want is for there to be no animation when the page is loaded.
Here's the [JSBin project](http://jsbin.com/qesufa/edit?css,output).

Comment: There is no start animation in my chrome.

Comment: I'm not getting any start animation on page load.

Comment: No start animation! What browser are you using?

Comment: Oops! I forgot to add something to the CSS. There's supposed to be a `animation: menushrink 0.3s linear;` in the menu CSS. My appologies!

Comment: why not just not add the animation of menu shrink to a class so, when the user mouseouts, the class gets added at that point and then it'll animate?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's weird that I'm answering my own question.

I figured out the answer thanks to @Daemedeor. [Here's the final result](http://jsbin.com/qesufa). What I did was I put the `onmouseout` which directed to my Javascript function `menuout()` (obviously you could change that, I just chose that name). My javascript code ended up being:

```
function menuout() {
  document.getElementById("menu").className += " menuanimate";
}
```

And my HTML code was:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Menu</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu" onmouseout="menuout()" id="menu">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And last but not least my CSS:

```
@keyframes menugrow {
  0% {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
  }
  25% {
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
  }
  100% {
    height:100vh;
    width:30%;
  }
}
@keyframes menushrink {
  0% {
    width:30%;
    height:100vh;
  }
  75% {
    width:30%;
    height:50px;
  }
  100% {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
  }
}
.menu {
  background:#1a1a1a;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
.menu:hover {
  animation: menugrow 0.3s linear;
  height:100vh;
  width:30%;
}
body {
  margin:0px;
}
.menuanimate {
  animation:menushrink 0.3s linear;
}
```